# Is there any way to find out mapped drive in Java?

Tags: java, java-io

I want to find out a given drive path is mapped drive or normal drive in my Java code. Is there any API already available for that?

Comment: Note that you can access native APIs with JNA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use WMI for this, either use a WMI library for Java, or call `wmic.exe`. Looks to be a fairly simple query, `Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4`

As a reference: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/10/27/how-can-i-determine-which-drives-are-mapped-to-network-shares.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about drive letters, then there is no concept of that in Java. Java tries to be cross-platform, and most platforms have no concept of drive letters.